# Rails 3 & Paperclip issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am very new to rails and trying to get paperclip working for user profiles on my site. I setup the paperclip gem in my gemfile and bundle installed. I was having an issue using :has_attached_file so I then used 'rails plugin install github/path/to/paperclip.git' and restarted webrick. After that everything seemed to be working as far as rendering my new form and giving me the option to upload a file.

When I try and upload a photo to a user profile it just takes me back to the page for the user without telling me it was successfully updated and without showing my newly uploaded image. It does adjust the name or email address if you change those. It doesn't look like it actually puts the image into the path that is listed on the readme on Github for paperclip. Is here some config file i'm not seeing?

I ran 'rails generate paperclip user photo' and below is some of the pertinent code:

From models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :name,  :presence   => true,
                    :length     => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  #code below tells rails that our users have photos
  has_attached_file :photo
end
```

From views/users/show.html.erb:

```
<b>Username: </b><%= @user.name %>
<p><b>Email Address: </b><%= @user.email %></p>
<p><b>Avatar: </b><% if @user.photo? %><%= image_tag @user.photo.url %><% else %>No      Photo Uploaded!<% end %></p>
```

From views/users/_form.html.erb

```
<% form_for :user, @user, :url => user_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name.to_s << ': ' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Email Address:' %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Avatar.to_s << ': ' %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Edit: adding controller code:
From controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate, :except => [:index]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
        **code removed for brevity**
      end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten this fixed. The issue seems to have been a problem with the _form partial I was using on the new user and edit user screen. I've left the bad template code in my original question and I'll post the fixed code here. The :user and :url => values were removed.

From /views/user/_form.html.erb

```
<% form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name.to_s << ': ' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Email Address:' %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Avatar.to_s << ': ' %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some questions: did you run `rake db:migrate` after `rails generate paperclip user photo`? In your controller do you actually have a `show` method that loads the saved user and thus displays the photo?

Also to display the `:notice` message you need to add it somewhere in your application template with `<%= flash[:notice] =>`.

Comment: I did run rake db:migrate to create the extra columns.

 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) -- this is my show action from the users controller.
  end